# Is it possible to receive incoming video call in Skype on a computer without camera and microphone?

Tags: skype, skype-for-windows-10

After a long time I have tried using Skype again and found it to be unusable.
I cannot receive video calls from another person. I do see an incoming call notification, but when I click "Accept" the call is interrupted. Sometimes with a message "Call declined" ??? And sometimes with a message "missed call".
I should point out that computer I am working on does not have a camera nor a microphone. But this should not be a problem. I have received calls in the past (older version of Skype) on the same computer with no problem.

Skype version 8.56.0.102
Application version 14.56.102.0

Comment: How would you communicate with them? What's the point of answering a video or voice call with no appropriate hardware? Initiate a text call if that's all you have.

Comment: @Tetsujin Why would you watch TV? Why don't you use telegrams?

Comment: Not a valid comparison.

Comment: "guest" could chat with someone, who does sign language via webcam ;)